# When accessing files in Firebase Cloud Storage from a client, is it more cost effective to fetch a file using a downloadURL vs getBlob?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

**In my web application which uses Firebase v9:**

Specific to downloading files from a firebase cloud storage bucket client side, I am concerned about cost and quotas.

**Which method is the most cost effective?**

1. use `getBlob()` to download a file.
2. use `getDownloadURL()` to obtain a download url, store it in the DB and subsequently fetch the file.

Looking at the documentation Firebase provides surrounding quotas it is not clear.

Are the quotas which are associated with calls to `getBlob()` more restrictive than using `getDownloadURL()` along with a subsequent http request to download the file?

**UPDATE:**

I understand that `getBlob()` provides more security via security rules as an alternative to retrieving a publicly accessible `downloadURL()`. In this case all files are meant to be publicly accessible.

I am concerned specifically about cost at scale over time and whether or not calls to `getBlob()` would be more cost effective vs having to call `getDownloadURL()` after every file upload, storing that result in the DB and subsequently making http request(s) to download the file.

It seems to me that the later would ultimately be more expensive in the long run, *unless* there is a restrictive or limiting quota associated with making calls to `getBlob()`.

Can anyone, preferably from the Firebase team if possible, tell me if a `getBlob()` call results in a greater impact to quota vs a call to `downloadURL()` plus subsequent http fetch request(s) to download.

Is there a difference in the long run *over time* since the later requires making that additional call to `getDownloadURL()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll still be charged for bandwidth same way as the `downloadURL`. There's a security benefit however, anyone with the `downloadURL` could see and download the image. But you can use `getBlob()` if you don't want to return a URL but download the file itself (protected by security rules). This way a user cannot share any `downloadURL`.

Checkout this [Firebase Release Notes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjENUKwjDEE&t=123s) video where this is explained in detail.

Comment: i appreciate and understand the note about security and was going to mention, but to keep the question focused i left out that detail. In my case all files are meant to be public so i was not concerned with security, but rather just cost at scale and whether or not one call to `getBlob()` would be more cost effective vs essentially what amounts to 2 calls, one to `getDownloadURL()` plus the subsequent http request to download. Wouldn't the latter be more expensive?

Comment: @DevMike bandwidth costs wise no. It'll save the additional time required to get the download URL for sure. There's no surcharge to get the download URL though.

Comment: That video was very useful thank you. Really it is quota that id like to understand in more detail. If there is no difference cost wise in using `getBlob()` vs an http request to a downloadURL, then that would answer my question i think.

Comment: @DevMike a 5 MB image is 5 MB irrespective of you download it using an URL or `getBlob()`. All `getBlob()` is doing internally generating auth and app check tokens to send along with the request. A normal download URL with ?token doesn't so it cannot check who is using the request. You are not billing for generating either of the tokens

Comment: If that is in-fact true, then i would think that would answer my question.

Comment: @DevMike Firebase SDKs are open source if you'd like to check that yourself.

Comment: Yes, i understand the comparison between an http fetch request vs what getBlob is doing under the hood. This does **not** confirm whether or not the cost / quotas associated to each are equal.  That is my question. Assume i am talking about hundreds of thousands of very small files. Over time i would expect that quota could impact cost.

Comment: @DevMike "what" quota? The only billable factors in your usage section is storage and bandwidth.

Comment: Are you suggesting that calling getBlob() only impacts bandwidth?  Reading the firebase documentation, there seems to be cost associated with almost every action or method call.

Comment: @DevMike are you referring to request (upload/download) count? It'll be 1 req irrespective of if you access via URL or getBlob().

Comment: Gotya. Ok thank you, and hey, I realize how i might be coming across here, i am just trying to be very careful. I do not want to wake up to find an enormous Firebase bill due to writing code that was not cost effective, and yes i have billing restrictions / alerts set, but i do not want my application to go down either as a result.